# Error when uploading image through richtexteditor in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, rich-text-editor

I have been added richtexteditor to MVC 5 project. It's work fine but when press on insert image or insert video it show two error message:

1. http error1 :404:Not Found
2. Unable to parse /richtexteditor/dialogs/uploadinfo.xml?2014040302 , failed to execute initialize : [uploadinfodialog:1] , Cannot read property 'Category' of undefined,

Comment: After spending 2 days found the problem, if you are trying to load editor through ajax this problem will exists.

Comment: the problem in AjaxPostbackUrl, it shouldn't change with ajax request.